# Out of memory issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, jquery, internet-explorer

One of my web Applications which uses auto-refresh after every 5 mins when run in Internet explorer gives **OUT OF MEMORY At LINE XXXX** error and then it has to be restarted.

My application makes a Ajax call every 5 minutes to get new Data and replace existing contents with new one. iam clearing all refrences to existing data so that it becomes garbage collection elgible and doesnt lead to memory leaks but still i get this error.

Any help would be good.....

Comment: Which IE version? I had a similar issue a while ago in IE6... couldn't really find a proper solution, so I had to remove the AJAX call for users of IE6.

Comment: Does it work with different browsers (firefox, opera, safari, ...) ?

Comment: can we see the code? maybe we can spot a memory leak. is the problem in the java (server-side?) or jquery (client-side)?

Answer (score 0):

If you get OutOfMemory on server side you have memory growth. I am sorry. :(
I'd suggest you to use one of popular Java profilers to locate the source of you problem. Alternative way is try to simplify the application as much you can. Good luck. I am sure that you can find the problem using profiler very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could see if this happen
http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html

Answer (score 0):

IE have limitation to number of element able to use + request timeout. If you use AJAX call to replace content, it should not make your memory up.

my suggest is that you run HttpWatch - http://www.httpwatch.com/

then trace down how many call you make, if it only one and page size never increase, you may have to optimize your code (use local variable instead of global etc).